# Check constraint fecha mayor que hoy NOW() en MySQL

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Cómo aplica ese constraint check para campo tipo datetime, necesito que solo acepte fechas mayores a la actual, incluso por minutos, es para agendar notas en el sistema, les dejos mis intentos:

```
ALTER TABLE telefono_contacto ADD CONSTRAINT CHECK_Hora_agenda CHECK (fecha_hora_contacto > 
TO_DATE(NOW()));

ALTER TABLE telefono_contacto ADD CONSTRAINT CHECK_Hora_agenda CHECK (fecha_hora_contacto > 
now());
```

Error Code: 1901. Function or expression 'current_timestamp()' cannot be used in the CHECK clause of `CHECK_Hora_agenda`

Menciono que la columna es DATETIME

Comment: Quítale el `TO_DATE()`, el `NOW()` por defecto viene en `DATETIME`

Comment: ¿Cuál es tu versión de MySQL?

Comment: La versión que uso es 5.0.12